# Large Layout Shift When Make Text to Bold

Tags: html, css

I am little new in HTML and CSS. I am building one simple site.
I have marked that when I make some text from paragraph bold, its causing large layout shift issue in PageSpeed Insights.

My page is [Best Teen Patti Games](https://paisalut.com/teen-patti-master-download/)

I am attaching screenshot of pagespeed insights.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried to generate GIF of CLS using
https://defaced.dev/tools/layout-shift-gif-generator/

I am trying to fix it from last one hour but not getting idea what to do for fix the issue. Let me know if someone here can help me for fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can give the whole text an increased line hight - high
enough to accommodate both the bold and the non-bold text?

```css
.p3 b {
  font-weight:normal;
}

.p3 b:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.p2 b {
}
p {
vertical-align: baseline;
}

div p:first-child { margin-top: 0 }
```

```html
<div style="column-count: 3;">
<p class="p1">Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold,</p>

<p class="p2">Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text<b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b></p>


<p class="p3">Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text<b> with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b></p>
</div>

<div style="column-count: 3; line-height: 26px; border-top: 1px gray solid; padding-top: 30px; margin-top: 30px;">
<p class="p1">Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold, Text without bold</p>

<p class="p2">Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text<b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b></p>


<p class="p3">Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>, Text <b>with bold</b>,  Text<b> with bold</b>,  Text <b>with bold</b></p>
</div>
```